# How does linux-kernel read proc/pid file?

Tags: ubuntu, process, linux-kernel, system-calls, pwd

How and Where does linux-kernel read proc/pid file which shows all processes in the system. I found linux-source-2.6.31/fs/proc/ Here there are files, but it is hard to understand because it is really complicated. Can someone knows, how it works?

Answer (score 8):

/proc is a pseudo-filesystem, meaning that its contents are not "real" files. Instead, the contents are a representation of the kernel's internal data structures. Therefore the kernel doesn't need to **read** them - it can already access the data directly.

/proc is used by user-mode (i.e. non-kernel) programs such as [`ps`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ps) to find out (for instance) about processes running on the system. There's a [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/5/proc) that describes much of what's available.

Answer (score 4):

You're looking in the right place.

Specifically, the function `proc_pid_readdir()` in `fs/proc/base.c` is used to fill out the list of pid entries when the `/proc` root directory is read.  You can see the basic loop around all processes and tasks in that function:

```
ns = filp->f_dentry->d_sb->s_fs_info;
iter.task = NULL;
iter.tgid = filp->f_pos - TGID_OFFSET;
for (iter = next_tgid(ns, iter);
     iter.task;
     iter.tgid += 1, iter = next_tgid(ns, iter)) {
    filp->f_pos = iter.tgid + TGID_OFFSET;
    if (proc_pid_fill_cache(filp, dirent, filldir, iter) < 0) {
        put_task_struct(iter.task);
        goto out;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Look in your /proc directory, there is a virtual file in there that lists all processes running in the system, even the binary program ps actually opens up that file in the /proc directory to output the listing of processes/pids..

[Linux ProcFs Guide](http://buffer.antifork.org/linux/procfs-guide.pdf)
[Linux Proc Filesystem as a Programmer's Tool](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/8381)